# How make a if statement more correctly? (If the random number contains a number from the list, then...)

Tags: python, if-statement, logic

i want to make a code (Lucky ticket, aka lottery) - with can generate random 6-dight number, after that - programm will check a list (with contain a lucky numbers for win: '11', '22', '33' and etc.) and say - are you win or not. But - theres one problem, i cant make if statement correctly, it always gives me error, not right result with i want. List are contain 9 values:
luckynumber = '11', '22', '33', '44', '55', '66', '77', '88', '99'.

Comment: Show what you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem you might be having is that in order to compare `random_number`with `lucky_numbers`, they both need to be strings i.e.,

```py
lucky_numbers = ['11', '22', '33', '44', '55', '66', '77', '88', '99']
random_number = str(random_number) # assuming you already made random_number
```

You can then compare the two with `any()`, e.g.

```py
result = any(r in random_number for r in lucky_number)
```

If you *don't* convert to `random_number` to a string, you'll get the error
`TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not interable`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if luckynumber in ["put all the lucky numbers in this list"]:
   pass # do whatever you want
```